# Mongo db update query is not working in embedded documents in azure cosmos db

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Embedded Update query works fine in mlab and atlas but not working in Cosmos DB:

My Collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5982f3f97729be2cce108785"),
    "password" : "$2y$10$F2P9ITmyKNebpoDaQ1ed4OxxMZSKmKFD9ipiU1klqio239c/nJcme",
    "nin" : "123",
    "login_status" : 1,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T09:09:03.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T06:08:47.000Z"),
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "abc",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T06:08:48.000Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T06:08:48.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5982f3f97729be2cce108784")
        }
    ],
    "name" : "demo",
    "email" : "email@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "1231234",

}
```

My query is:

```
db.rail_zones.update(
  {'_id': ObjectId("5982f3f97729be2cce108785"),
   'files._id' : ObjectId("5982f3f97729be2cce108784")},
  { $set: {'files.$.name' : "Changed"}})
```

I get this response:

```
"acknowledged" : true,
"matchedCount" : 0.0,
"modifiedCount" : 0.0
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the question? please explain..

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tested this issue on my side and found the Array Update could not work as expected. I assumed that the **Array Update** feature has not been implemented in the MongoDB Compatibility layer of Azure CosmosDB. Moreover, I found a feedback [Positional array update via '$' query support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api/suggestions/20091454-positional-array-update-via-query-support) talking about the similar issue.